# Error in matMul: inner shapes (1) and (2) of Tensors with shapes 684,1 and 2,1 and transposeA=false and transposeB=false must match

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, linear-regression, tensorflow.js

I am complete beginner to AI as well as tensorflow.js. Currently following the Machine Learning course of Stephen Grider. I should have got a output after the following code but instead i got error. Please help:

code:
linear-regression.js:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');


class LinearRegression {
    constructor(features, labels, options) {
        this.features = tf.tensor(features);
        this.labels = tf.tensor(labels);

        this.features = tf.ones([this.features.shape[0], 1]).concat(this.features) //generates the column of one for the horse power 
        this.options = Object.assign(
            { learningRate: 0.1, iterations: 1000 }, 
            options
        ); //default value is 0.1, if the learning rate is provided, the value is overrided... iteration no. of times gradient decent runs

        this.weights = tf.zeros([2, 1]); // intial tensor of both m and b are zeros
    }

    gradientDescent() {
        const currentGuesses = this.features.matMul(this.weights); //matMul is matrix multiplication which is features * weights
        const differences = currentGuesses.sub(this.labels); //(features * weights) - labels

        const slopes = this.features
            .transpose()
            .matMul(differences)
            .div(features.shape[0]); // slope of MSE with respect to both m and b. features * ((features * weights) - labels) / total no. of features.
        

        this.weights = this.weights.sub(slopes.mul(this.options.learningRate));

    }

    train() {
        for (let i=0; i < this.options.iterations; i++) {
            this.gradientDescent();
        }

        /*test(testFeatures, testLabels) {
            testFeatures = tf.tensor(testFeatures);
            testLabels = tf.tensor(testLabels);
        } */
    }
}

module.exports = LinearRegression;
```

index.js:

```
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const loadCSV = require('./load-csv');
const LinearRegression = require('./linear-regression');

let { features, labels, testFeatures, testLabels } =loadCSV('./cars.csv', {
    shuffle: true,
    splitTest: 50,
    dataColumns: ['horsepower'],
    labelColumns: ['mpg']
});

const regression = new LinearRegression(features, labels, {
    learningRate: 0.002,
    iterations: 100
});

regression.train();



console.log(
    'Updated M is:', 
    regression.weights.get(1, 0), 
    'Updated B is:', 
    regression.weights.get(0, 0)
    );
```

Error:

```
D:\Application Development\MLKits-master\MLKits-master\regressions\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\ops\operation.js:32
            throw ex;
            ^

Error: Error in matMul: inner shapes (1) and (2) of Tensors with shapes 684,1 and 2,1 and transposeA=false and transposeB=false must match.
    at Object.assert (D:\Application Development\MLKits-master\MLKits-master\regressions\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\util.js:36:15)
    at matMul_ (D:\Application Development\MLKits-master\MLKits-master\regressions\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\ops\matmul.js:25:10)
    at Object.matMul (D:\Application Development\MLKits-master\MLKits-master\regressions\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\ops\operation.js:23:29)
    at Tensor.matMul (D:\Application Development\MLKits-master\MLKits-master\regressions\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tensor.js:315:26)
    at LinearRegression.gradientDescent (D:\Application Development\MLKits-master\MLKits-master\regressions\linear-regression.js:19:46)
    at LinearRegression.train (D:\Application Development\MLKits-master\MLKits-master\regressions\linear-regression.js:34:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Application Development\MLKits-master\MLKits-master\regressions\index.js:18:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is thrown by

> this.features.matMul(this.weights)

There is a matrice multiplication between `this.features` of shape `[684, 1]` and `this.weights` of shape `[2, 1]`. To be able to multiply a matrice A (shape `[a, b]`) with B (shape `[c, d]`), `b` and `c` should match which is not the case here.

To solve the issue here, `this.weights` should be transposed

```
this.features.matMul(this.weights, false, true)
```

Comment: it did work :(  it gives error:  Error: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes 684,2 and 342,1. please help!

Comment: What is the shape of `this.features` and `this.weights` ? As an example, if you run the following: `tf.ones([684, 1]).matMul(tf.ones([2, 1]), false, true).print()`, you will see that it works

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can i get back to you after i finish the linear regression part of the course? In next 24 hours. Thanks!

Comment: hey mate thanks trying to help me out! It got solved after i finished up the course

Comment: By transposing the tensors ?

Comment: Nope but with setting the size of weights as this.features.shape[1]

Comment: Yeah anyway as explained in my answer, if you modify the shape to match, then it will work. If the answer helped, could you upvote it and mark it as accepted ?